# Why am I only getting this React Native navigation error when navigating to one specific component and not others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation

I am currently working on a React Native chat application that basically uses these components: "Home", "Login", and "Chat" - each component being a screen/page.

navigate component error:

[image]

In this instance, I am trying to use:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} />
```

in order to go back to the 'Home' component from the 'Chat' component, but it throws the above error and I have to reload the app.

```
return (
    <>
      <Header {...props} chat menuItems={menuItems} chatData={isGroup ? {name: groupName, avatar: groupImage} : recipient} isGroup={isGroup}
        chatTitle={
          <Content>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} style={{marginBottom: 30}}>
              <Icon size={33} height={40} name="chevron-left-outline" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 15}} onPress={navigateProfile}>
              <HeaderAvatar source={getAvatarPath(isGroup ? groupImage : recipient.avatar, isGroup)} />
              <View>
                <Name noFont>{isGroup ? groupName : recipient.name}</Name>
                {!isGroup && recipientTyping ? <StatusTxt>Typing...</StatusTxt> : isOnline ? <StatusTxt>Online</StatusTxt> : null}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Content>
        }
      />
      {loading ? <Loading/> :
        <View style={themeStyle.body}>
          <GiftedChat
            messages={messagesData}
            user={{_id: user._id}}
            minInputToolbarHeight={60}
            renderMessageVideo={renderVideoMessage}
            renderMessage={props => {
              if (props.currentMessage.audio)
                return <AudioPlayer {...props} currentAudioId={currentAudioId} you={(props.currentMessage._id === currentAudioId).toString()} setCurrentAudioId={setCurrentAudioId} />;
              if (props.currentMessage.text){
                if(typeof(props.currentMessage.text) === 'string')
                  return <Message {...props} />
                else 
                props.currentMessage.text = (props.currentMessage?.text.find(i => i.language === user.language))?.text;
                return <Message {...props} />
              }
              return <Message {...props} />;
            }}
            renderBubble={props => {
              if (props.currentMessage.location) return <LocationMessage location={props.currentMessage.location} messagePosition={props.position} />;
              else {
                const allProps = {...props, ...bubbleProps};
                return <Bubble {...allProps} />;
              }
            }}
            renderAvatar={props => <Avatar {...props} containerStyle={{left: {top: -10, marginRight: 0}}} />}
            renderInputToolbar={() => <ChatInput value={message} onChange={setMessage} onSend={onSend} appendMessage={appendMessage} updateMessageData={updateMessageData} />}
            extraChatData={{currentAudioId}}
            listViewProps={{ListFooterComponent: renderLoadMoreBtn}}
          />
        </View>
      }
    </>
```

I have tried using:

```
props.navigation.goBack()
```

but this also throws the same above error.

However, `props.navigation.navigate('Login')` works without throwing any errors. When trying to navigate to the 'Login' component from the 'Chat' component, it will briefly redirect to the Login screen before redirecting again to the Home screen.

Also a separate possibly related error:

new chat error:

[image]

After setting .navigate() to the Login component and after redirecting to the Home component from the Chat component, this error began to show when trying to navigate to the Chat component again. Reloading isn't necessary with this error in order to continue using the app, but I am still unsure why the error is being thrown.

Anybody know why only navigating directly back to the "Home" component crashes the app?

Here is the component with the navigation script:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useColorScheme, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {Chat, Home, Login, SignUp, UserProfile, Profile, GroupProfile, MediaManager} from "../screens";
import {theme} from "./theme";
import saga from "./saga";
import {useInjectSaga} from "../utils/injectSaga";
import {navigationRef} from './Navigator';
import LinkWeb from "../screens/LinkWeb";
import BlockedList from "../screens/BlockedList";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const appNavigator = () => {
  const routeNameRef = React.useRef();
  const scheme = useColorScheme();
  useInjectSaga({key: 'root', saga});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (scheme === 'dark') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(theme.dark.bg);
        StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content');
      }, 100);
    }
  }, []);

  const MyTheme = React.useMemo(() => ({
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      background: scheme === 'dark' ? theme.dark.bg : theme.light.bg
    },
  }), [scheme]);

  const stackOptions = React.useMemo(() => ({headerShown: false}), []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      theme={MyTheme} ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;}}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;
        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName && scheme !== 'dark') {
          if (currentRouteName === 'UserProfile') {
            StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content');
            StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#000')
          } else {
            StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');
            StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#fff')
          }
        }
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={stackOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="UserProfile" component={UserProfile}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="GroupProfile" component={GroupProfile}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="LinkWeb" component={LinkWeb}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="BlockedList" component={BlockedList}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="MediaManager" component={MediaManager}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default appNavigator;
```

Comment: please include your navigation script

Answer (score 0):

Super simple solution:

Just had to update my react-native-gifted-chat version.